# How to show the drive size in QDirModel

Tags: c++, qt

I want to show the drive size in `QDirModel`. I try to rewrite the "Data" function, but fail. how can I do it? thanks.

note:

```
setData: setData(const QModelIndex & index, const QVariant & value, int role)
QVariant QDirModel::data(const QModelIndex & index, int role) const
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what "fail" means in this instance?  (FWIW I suspect that the problem is that the QVariant you are returning is holding a quint64, and the calling function expects it to hold a QString; if so, the solution would be to convert the quint64 to a QString and pass that to the QVariant constructor instead)

Comment: First,thanks your reply. it's not this reason. I have edit my code. now I'm not sure in order to show the drive size in QTreeView and rewrite which funtion? data or setData?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Qt documentation: [QDir Class Reference](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdir.html) , [QFileInfo Class Reference](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfileinfo.html)

use `QDir::drives()`

```
QFileInfoList QDir::drives () [static]
```

> Returns a list of the root directories on this system.
>
> On Windows this returns a list of QFileInfo objects containing "C:/", "D:/", etc. On other operating systems, it returns a list containing just one root directory (i.e. "/").

```
qint64 QFileInfo::size () const
```

> Returns the file size in bytes. If the file does not exist or cannot be fetched, 0 is returned.

Comment: thanks your reply.After obtain the drive size, and how to show the size in QTreeView (size in the sencond column)?

Comment: I have get the drive size by using windows api. My main problem is how to show the drive size in QTreeView? thanks.